# Closing a question without even a comment

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

It is my understanding that due to this StackExchange's infancy, questions that otherwise may seem close-worthy, shall stay open if they aid in the discussion of Cardano and help in forming this StackExchange's character.

I would like to discuss the closing of this question:

[What's happened with Cardano Proof of University Diplomas in Greece?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/745/whats-happened-with-cardano-proof-of-university-diplomas-in-greece)

Unfortunately, this question has been closed without an explanation.
Personally, I found this to be an excellent question. I also wanted to know the status of this project. Why has it been closed? What is "off-topic" about it? What would have to change in the question to make it on-topic?

If other community members think this is a valid question, please make use of your reopen vote.

Comment: I also agree that was a great question. Maybe the Cardano team will be able to answer (even if the cooperation is not active anymore).

Comment: Who do you mean by Cardano team?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, closing questions without a comment is poor form.  It doesn't help the poster understand why it was closed and how to improve or indicate a better forum to raise the same question. We should discourage it in all but the most extreme cases (somebody asks a question that has nothing to do with Cardano)

Allowing questions about events and specific projects sets a precedent that is highly likely to be abused.  It could lead to spam, self-promotion and weakening of this site's value. - that's why I voted to close it when it appeared in my queue.

I believe that, to be relevant here, questions should rarely have answers that change over time and about Cardano itself rather than the projects and opportunities that are on it.  In my opinion this question failed on both those counts.

Answer (score 0):

I did vote to close it as it did not appear to be really connected with Cardano, but to a closed Enterprise version planned by IOG back in the past.

All I found is a press release, not even issued by IOG, describing a potential project that someone could build on Cardano. So, as far as I know, all it ever was is a press release without a real project.

We can discuss if we want to allow discussion about projects build on top of Cardano technology (not the Cardano mainnet blockchain). I mean, is this SE a good place for project such as Emurgo Tracability? Probably not, but that's just my opinion I'm open to change.

I would be interested if discussion about Hyperledger or Quroum are allowed on the Etherum SE?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I found this on Charles Hoskinson's Twitter: https://twitter.com/IOHK_Charles/status/1140567328331128832

Comment: I think that is about Atala in Georgia. I think my take on it is: If the solution is open and based on Cardano, we can consider it Cardano related. If the solution is proprietary and we do not know how integrated with Cardano it is, let's consider is an off-topic?